# Установка плагинов от 3DSMax 2012 на 2018 завершается ошибкой 127

Tags: 3dsmax

Установка плагинов 3DSMax 2018 (dle, dli, dlo, gup) завершается с ошибкой 127.

Когда я скопировал файлы плагинов в папку `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\3ds Max 2018\Plugins`, получаю ошибка 127 (Код ошибки 127 - Указанная процедура не найдена.).

Что делать? Плагин сделан для 3DSMax 2012.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: За такой промежуток времени в 3dsmax-е 2018 могло всё в корне поменяться, точки входа в плагины, входные параметры, окружение плагинов, да что угодно. Ищите новую версию плагина, совместимую с 2018 версией макса. | Plugins system may be changed the in 2018 version. Too many versions skipped. Try find this plugin version for 2018.

Comment: @Arhad, пожалуйста, перечитайте вторую правку от автора, мне кажется, вы не правильно исправили заголовок... (я к тому, что плагин у него 2012 года, а ставит он его на 2018 макс, в вашем варианте заголовка читается всё наоборот)

Comment: @test123, спасибо, исправил.